# I have this MIPS code for a Fibonacci Function. How can I extend the code for printing the given position in terminal?

Tags: function, assembly, mips, fibonacci

I have this MIPS code for a Fibonacci function,one pass a natural number in terminal and the program returns the Fibonacci number in that position, but it's not working, how can I modify the code to do so? I almost got it, but need some help :)

This the current code i got:

```
.data 
    ask4num: .asciiz "Enter a number: "
    printNum: .asciiz "\nThe number on the Lucas Sucession is: "
    
.text
    
.globl main

main:
    # print text
    addi $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, ask4num
    syscall
    
    # get number
    addi $v0, $zero, 5
    syscall
    
    # store number in $t0
    addi $t0, $v0, 0
    
    # prit text
    addi $v0, $zero, 4
    la $a0, printNum
    syscall
    
    jal Fib
    
    addi $v0, $zero, 1
    addi $a0, $v1, 0
    syscall
    
    addi $v0, $zero, 10
    syscall
    
Fib:

    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $a0, 4($sp)
    sw $s0, 8($sp)
    
    beq $a0, $zero, ReturnZero
    addiu $t0, $zero, 0
    slti $t0, $a0, 2
    bne $t0, $zero, ReturnOne
    
    addi $a0, $a0, -1
    jal Fib
    
    move $s0, $v0
    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    addi $a0, $a0, -2
    jal Fib
    
    add $v0, $v0, $s0
    
    lw $s0, 8($sp)
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addiu $sp, $sp, 12
    jr $ra
    
    ReturnZero:
    lw $s0, 8($sp)
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addiu $sp, $sp, 12
    li $v0, 0
    jr $ra

    ReturnOne:
    lw $s0, 8($sp)
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 12
    li $v0, 1
    jr $ra
```

The program is almost done just need some help to fix it, its probably easy to do. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Your Fib function returns in v0 not v1.  Copy v0 to a0 (before setting v0=1 as the call number for print_int, of course.  Was that why you used `addi $a0, $v1, 0` to print some register you never used anywhere else in your program?)

Comment: Try debugging it: use single step and observe its workings.